# Should PHP variables be initialized prior to use as an OUT function parameter?

Tags: php, pointers, pass-by-reference

What is the correct way to write code that calls a function that accepts a variable pointer and changes the value?

The following works, but my IDE complains that $v is an undefined variable, which it is until the function it calls sets a value:

```
function foo(&$bar) {
  $bar = 12345;
}

foo($v);
```

Should I initialize $v first to satisfy my IDE? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
$v = NULL;
foo($v);
```

Comment: Just curious, do you have a good reason to use a variable reference over a return value?

Comment: No, you can't get around it. You're using an undefined variable in a function call. The warning is unavoidable.

Comment: @zzzzBov our vendor libraries use this pattern (personally I dislike it).

Comment: "Satisfy your IDE"? Is that how you think about programming, or life? Work until everyone stops complaining? You have to write *correct code that makes sense*. If your function wants to modify an external variable, then that variable *has to exist*, so you have to create it first before calling the function.

Comment: Why would initialising the variable be a bad idea? It's generally best practice to do so.

Comment: @MattGibson, I can understand using someone elses code as an initializer, where code that should be written as `$foo = bar()` needs to be written as `bar($foo);` to set it.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I may have phrased my question poorly.  I don't wish to eliminate the warning for the purpose of making my IDE happy.  I wish to know if this is idiomatic PHP (passing an undefined variable) or not.  I use this example because the PHP manual uses this exact pattern and it felt wrong, and my IDE pointed out something that bugged me anyway. The code works fine, so I know it technically works, but I do not wish to write poor code just because it works in the current version of PHP.

Comment: @zzzzBov Do you mean that would be an OK approach? Isn't there a risk that $foo may already have been set somehow and bar() then does something unexpected?

Comment: @MattGibson, no, I don't think it's ok to *not* initialize a variable being passed by reference, I'm simply stating that I understand why a developer would want to.

Answer (score 6):

When passing a variable by reference to a function, you need to have a reference to the variable from the calling code. To have a reference, the variable needs to exist. To exist, the variable needs to be initialized.

I recommend setting it to a reasonable default value. If the reasonable default is `null`, then use `null`. In some cases it may be more reasonable to use `''` or `0` depending on what type of value you want the variable to hold.